# Can you avoid subqueries on MySQL for better performance?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have to add 3 dates on a query result but those dates are on diferents rows of another table.

Table COMP

```
+---------+-------------+----------+
| id_comp | comp_status | comp_guy |
+---------+-------------+----------+
| 456     | 8           | 23       |
| 457     | 7           | 67       |
| 458     | 3           | 34       |
+---------+-------------+----------+
```

Table EVA

```
+--------+---------+----------+------------+
| id_eva | id_comp | eva_type | eva_date   |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+
| 3456   | 456     | 1        | 2018-01-09 |
| 3457   | 456     | 2        | 2018-01-12 |
| 3458   | 456     | 3        | 2018-01-11 |
| 3459   | 457     | 1        | 2018-01-09 |
| 3460   | 457     | 2        | 2018-01-03 |
| 3461   | 457     | 3        | 2018-01-02 |
+--------+---------+----------+------------+
```

I am using a query like this:

```
select 
comp.id_comp,
(select eva.eva_date from eva where eva.eva_type = 1 and eva.id_comp = comp.id_comp) as eva_one
(select eva.eva_date from eva where eva.eva_type = 2 and eva.id_comp = comp.id_comp) as eva_two
(select eva.eva_date from eva where eva.eva_type = 3 and eva.id_comp = comp.id_comp) as eva_thr
comp.status,
comp.guy
from
comp
left join eva on (eva.id_comp = comp.id_comp)
```

Result:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+-----+
| id_comp | eva_one     | eva_two     | eva_thr    | status | guy |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+-----+
| 456     | 2018-01-09  | 2018-01-12  | 2018-01-11 | 8      | 23  |
| 457     | 2018-01-09  | 2018-01-03  | 2018-01-02 | 7      | 67  |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+-----+
```

Is there a way to avoid the 3 subqueries? It takes too long to get the result.

Comment: Without from clauses, those aren't really exactly subqueries in some senses; I'm not sure how you even were able to get that result from the query.

Comment: You seem to be assuming cause and effect. But that said, I prefer to handle issues of data display in application code.

Comment: I edited the 3 little queries adding the from clause :) @Uueerdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was me, I'd probably use a query like the following, and handle any further display logic in application code (assuming that's available)...

```
SELECT c.*
     , e.eva_type
     , e.eva_date 
  FROM comp c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN eva e 
    ON e.id_comp = c.id_comp;
```

For any further issues concerning performance, we'd really need to see SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for the relevant tables, as well as the results of the EXPLAIN for the preferred query.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a pivot query:

```
SELECT 
comp.id_comp,
MAX(CASE eva.eva_type WHEN 1 THEN eva.eva_date END) AS eva_one,
MAX(CASE eva.eva_type WHEN 2 THEN eva.eva_date END) AS eva_two,
MAX(CASE eva.eva_type WHEN 3 THEN eva.eva_date END) AS eva_thr,
comp.status,
comp.guy
FROM comp
JOIN eva ON (eva.id_comp = comp.id_comp)
GROUP BY comp.id_comp
```

Tested on MySQL 5.7 with sql_mode including `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. MySQL 5.7 can infer that comp.status and comp.guy are functionally dependent on comp.id_comp, assuming the latter is the primary key.

Output:

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+--------+------+
| id_comp | eva_one    | eva_two    | eva_thr    | status | guy  |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+--------+------+
|     456 | 2018-01-09 | 2018-01-12 | 2018-01-11 |      8 |   23 |
|     457 | 2018-01-09 | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-02 |      7 |   67 |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+--------+------+
```

It's not clear whether you intend to use INNER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN. You showed LEFT [OUTER] JOIN in your question, but the result doesn't include a row for comp_id 458, perhaps because there are no rows in eva for that comp_id? Which suggests an INNER JOIN.

Comment: This query will only work if 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' as sql_mode is disabled or not active on the MySQL server.. Besides i don't trust MySQL's "functional dependency" when using SQL standard invalid GROUP BY queries because i believe saw i some execution differences between MySQL versions can't remember what it was it was some time ago..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I tested on MySQL 5.7 and it works.

Comment: then i assuming `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled.  Test it with `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY');` before running your query.

Comment: I did confirm ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is in my sql_mode. I just ran a default MySQL 5.7 config in a sandbox instance. `@@sql_mode: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: FWIW, I trust the functional dependency that arises in this instance

Comment: Granted, I don't think there are any *other* brands of RDBMS that support functional dependency detection in GROUP BY queries. So it's a bit risky getting used to writing this kind of query if you need to write code to work on other brands.

Comment: " I don't think there are any other brands of RDBMS that support functional dependency detection in GROUP BY queries." Latest SQL Server versions also supports "functional dependency" i believe.. "So it's a bit risky getting used to writing this kind of query if you need to write code to work on other brands" Yes very true.

Comment: Of course, nothing prevents from grouping on `comp.id_comp, comp.status, comp.guy`.

Comment: I learned that PostgreSQL 9.1 (circa 2011) also supports functional dependency detection for GROUP BY.